# Android: cant download big size Database from real website to SQLite database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I am making an app that needs to download data from web. It converts the data in mysql -> JSON -> sqlite database. **The download features worked fine with the dummy database using xampp in emulator.** But, when I change the URL address, the emulator couldn't get the database from web. **So I tried using my phone, the application worked fine when it download small database (around 50-100 rows, with total around 200KB), but it failed when I tried to download 2MB sized database (which has 22.000 rows in .sql)**

Is there any limitation in size or rows to download in apps, especially SQLite database? Or did I miss something? Also, how to see the database I downloaded in my phone? I already checked Show Hidden Folders in MyFiles setting, but I couldn't find my apps package..

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Does your JSON interface make key reposition? Perhaps your connection is limiting. The best approach is commit in small packets both in JSON and insert data that allows commit every packet

Comment: Im sorry. whats key reposition? i am still new at this. i was told to use inserthelper. Is it related to the method that commits in small packets?

Comment: When it does JSON activity, the layout still stays the same (which looks like its froze though it isnt) until a popup message appears which signifies download has completed

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have swap paging memory like a PC.  You can only use the physical memory that the device has.  With this information the limit becomes the memory occupied by the JSON, your class, your database.

You'll have to download N rows process N rows in a loop.  But the plus side is you could restart such an operation and include a cool progress bar for the user to look at while her storage is being eaten up by a large database.

Comment: So you meant I wont be able to locate the database file in my phone? My app will show pop up menu when it finishes downloading. It did show pop up menu. But there also showed toast message that is resulted from try catch exception from converting sql to JSON

Comment: If I am able to locate DB file I had downloaded, it would be better. So i will be able to find out whats wrong. I will copy the DB from phone to PC so I can see my DB result. Is it not possible?